# Source of telemetry data from games

Tags: data-request, api, games

I'm building model to predict behaviours of players. I'm looking for external source of telemetry data from games.

Have you any idea where can I get this kind of data from?

Comment: what kind of games? board games, cell phone games, video games, computer games, sports, ...?

Comment: *telemetry*?? Why is that necessary ([definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Telemetry))? Your question needs a lot more information; please [read this](https://opendata.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/284/how-a-good-data-request-question-should-look-like)